# Find and replace text in excel with specified font name

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm using Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library. My goal is to find text with specified font name and replace with new text.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 xlApp.FindFormat.Font.Name = "Arial";
 workSheet.Cells.Replace('a', 'b', Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, xlApp.FindFormat, Type.Missing);
```

but it does not works.

So how to find string with specified font name and replace with new string?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not that fluent with c# here is the vb.net code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Class1
Sub TEST()

    Dim xlapp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    xlapp.FindFormat.Font.Name = "Arial"

    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")

    wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace(What:="*", Replacement:="eee", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False)

End Sub
End Class
```

I ran a convertor which spat out C#:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
public class Class1
{

public void TEST()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    xlapp.FindFormat.Font.Name = "Arial";

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = default(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook);

    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xlsx");

    wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Replace(What: "*", Replacement: "eee", LookAt: XlLookAt.xlWhole, SearchOrder: XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase: false, SearchFormat: true, ReplaceFormat: false);

}
}
```