# Word interop - find and replace text in Symbol font onlyl

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I want to find and replace text in a Word document only if it is in the Symbol font using C#

This is my code so far:

```
static void find_replace_text(string find_s, string replace_s, Document document)
{
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Range rng = document.Range(0, document.Content.End);
    Find findObject = rng.Find;
    findObject.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Text = find_s;
    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Replacement.Text = replace_s;
    findObject.Font.Name = "Symbol";
    findObject.Format = true;


    object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, true,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

My code does not give me the expected result. When I remove the lines that set the font name and the format to true, then my code replaces all occurrences of the search string regardless of the font. For instance, I am trying to replace the alpha symbol (from Symbol font) that has character code 97. Without the font name being set in the code all occurrences of the letter 'a' (ascii 97) are replaced. I need the code to be font aware.

**UPDATE**

I can now confirm that the code works only in the case where the symbols have been added to WORD by changing the font to 'SYMBOL', but not when the symbol has been added to the document via the Symbol UI (which, unfortunately is how it was done in the documents I need to process).

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: This post may help -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440580/find-and-replace-text-in-excel-with-specified-font-name

Comment: It stillis not clear why you need to remove the code that specifies the font name when the font name is a key criterion for your search.

Comment: @bibadia The code gives me a result when I remove the font name. With the font name in the search it does not, and I thought it contained an error. I now can confirm that the code works, but that there is an oddity with WORD. There are two ways to add Symbols: by changing the font directly (in which case the code works), or by going through the Symbol UI. When going through the Symbol UI the font does not change and the code can therefore not detect that it is a symbol. Unfortunately in the documents that I need to parse, the symbols have been added via the latter method.

Comment: @J.Reynolds OK, I thought it might be that. There's a discussion here which may help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bed16cf1-0c39-4fce-85c2-c48632aab095/symbols-and-fields